# How to download pdf file using vuejs and bootstrap-vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to upload a `pdf` file to my browser, but I want to be able to download this file afterwards. I am having problems on the second task - downloading it.

I'm uploading as follow:

```
<b-form-file v-model="form.file" :state="Boolean(form.file)" placeholder="Choose a file..."></b-form-file>
```

How can I download `form.file` content after upload is done?

**Edit:**

I found [this](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js#examples) API, which handles file downloads nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the file somewhere on your server or on a storage service (ie Amazon S3) and then redirect the user to a link where the file itself is served.

The specific implementation is based on your backend implementation and your architectural choices.